# Can't launch nodejs + express basic program

Tags: node.js, express

I am having a bit of trouble with a basic nodejs and express program.

The problem is when I use `npm start` which should run node .\bin\www I get these errors:

```
C:\Users\{USRNAME}\Desktop\projets\cdc\cdc-api>npm start

cdc-api@0.0.0 start C:\Users\{USRNAME}\Desktop\projets\cdc\cdc-api
node .\bin\www


events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
    at Function.app.listen (C:\Users\{USRNAME}\Desktop\projets\cdc\cdc-api\node_mo
dules\express\lib\application.js:556:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\{USRNAME}\Desktop\projets\cdc\cdc-api\bin\www:
7:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)

npm ERR! cdc-api@0.0.0 start: `node .\bin\www`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cdc-api@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the cdc-api package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node .\bin\www
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls cdc-api
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\{USRNAME}\Desktop\projets\cdc\cdc-api
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\{USRNAME}\Desktop\projets\cdc\cdc-api\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

C:\Users\{USRNAME}\Desktop\projets\cdc\cdc-api>
```

and here is what I have in npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.28
3 info using node@v0.10.32
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
6 info prestart cdc-api@0.0.0
7 info start cdc-api@0.0.0
8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 info cdc-api@0.0.0 Failed to exec start script
10 error cdc-api@0.0.0 start: `node .\bin\www`
10 error Exit status 8
11 error Failed at the cdc-api@0.0.0 start script.
11 error This is most likely a problem with the cdc-api package,
11 error not with npm itself.
11 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
11 error     node .\bin\www
11 error You can get their info via:
11 error     npm owner ls cdc-api
11 error There is likely additional logging output above.
12 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
13 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
14 error cwd C:\Users\Moucheg\Desktop\projets\cdc\cdc-api
15 error node -v v0.10.32
16 error npm -v 1.4.28
17 error code ELIFECYCLE
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have tried everything I found on internet (reinstall node, recreate package.json, ...) I can't get it to work.

FYI, I am on Windows 8 (if it's of any help)

Thank you in advance for your help guys (and girls ;)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error "EADDRINUSE" means the port you're attempting to use is already in use by your system. Try changing the port used in your app or closing whatever program is using it.

Comment: as a followup, checkout the list of error codes for libuv [here](http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/basics.html#error-handling). That will help you greatly in debugging Node apps.

Comment: -_- I must be the unluckiest man on earth, I had thought about that and had tried to change it 3 times and that hadn't changed anything. Thanks !!

Answer (score -1):

The error means that the port is currently in use. 
Update the code to use a different port. Often times, node.js/express samples assign the port in `app.js`.

Answer (score -1):

`EADDRINUSE` happens when your code is using the same port of another program.
You can try to use another port to see if the problem is resolved.

Comment: Before writing a new answer you should check if others have already answered the same thing and only add a new answer if something is wrong with the exisiting answers.
The accepted answer says exactly the same thing (and this question is 6 years old :P)